# Parsing nested brackets in php

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match-all

I'm trying to parse a string consisting of nested brackets into an multidimensional associative array in php, which seems to be much harder as I thought. As an example I've got the following string:

```
{"stations":[{"id":"000000022","name":"Basel","score":null,"coordinate":{"type":"WGS84","x":47.547408,"y":7.589547},"distance":null}]}
```

And I'm trying to achieve the following array as output:

```
array(1) {
  ["stations"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(9) "000000022"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Basel"
    ["score"]=>
    string(4) "null"
    ["coordinate"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(5) "WGS84"
      ["x"]=>
      string(9) "47.547408"
      ["y"]=>
      string(8) "7.589547"
    }
    ["distance"]=>
    string(4) "null"
  }
}
```

I've searched on this for hours but didn't come up with anything close to a solution. Anyone got an idea on this?

Comment: You realize that this is JSON and there's a function to decode it? (it's not called "parsing")

Comment: [json_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: No, I acctually didn't realize that. You gave me the missing hint. Thanks a lot for pointing that out!